# Strictly convex norms instead of inner products on the tangent spaces

Tags: vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds

On differentiable manifolds, is there a term for functions $f$ from the tangent bundle to the real line such that for all points of the manifold, the restriction of $f$ to that point's tangent space is a [strictly convex](http://mathsci.ucd.ie/~rsmith/pdfs/talks/new%20york%20july%202011.pdf) norm and 
 the restriction of $ f$ to the complement of the zero subbundle is smooth?

Is there a term for a manifold together with such a function?

Comment: (I started wondering about this while I was taking a class on Riemannian manifolds.) $\hspace{1.43 in}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Strictly convex Finsler metric* or *strictly convex Finsler structure*. [Usage examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22strictly%20convex%20Finsler%22). Unfortunately, "strictly convex Finsler manifold" is likely to be confused with geodesic convexity of a manifold; which is probably why this particular combination did not   come up in search.

If you don't insist on the "strictly convex" part, then it's just a [Finsler manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold).